# How is the solution for \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$ current gain of a BJT derived?

Tags: current, bjt, gain, math

I'm just an enthusiast, and not too good at maths; I'm exploring constant current source circuits, in doing so I came across two equations for BJT current gain:

Could someone help me understand how \$\alpha\$ and \$\beta\$ are derived to the equations below:

\$\alpha=\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\$ and \$\beta=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\$

I know that:

\$I_c=\alpha I_e\$ and \$I_c=\beta I_b\$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Found some rich content here 
[electronics-tutorials-transistors](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html)

> *α and β Relationship in a NPN Transistor*
>   [image]
>
> The value of Beta for most standard NPN transistors can be found in the manufactures data sheets.

Comment: Why don't you copy and paste the vital parts of the linked page? This answer is correct at the moment but if that website dies this answer becomes useless.

Comment: Thank you for making a point. I just add the content here.

Comment: @binu Could you tell me mathematically, I know this is probably basic algebra, but I'm not familiar, how \$I_B=I_E - \alpha I_E\$ solves to \$I_B=I_E(1 - \alpha)\$ ? Really helpful insight this for me. Thanks Alex

Comment: @binu I presume, thinking about this if \$I_B=I_E - \alpha I_E\$ which is effectively \$I_B=1I_E - \alpha I_E\$ to give \$I_B=I_E(1 - \alpha)\$ makes sense.

Comment: @Alex2134 Yes it is. 
After getting out the common factor IE out,
***IB=IE−αIE*** can be factorize to ***IB=IE(1−α)***.  
Further :  factoring  an algebraic expression  
a(b + c) = ab + ac , 
ab + ac = a(b + c) , 
in here a = ***IE***, b = ***1***, c = ***α***

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one more equation, which is that \$I_e = I_c + I_b\$